# How to install pam_mysql on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, mysql

I'm trying to install the `vsftpd` web interface, but it requires `pam_mysql` and I'm pretty sure I don't have this installed. Does anyone know how to install this on the Pi?

I'm using the latest version of Raspbian with PIXEL. I have `mysql` installed, as well as `php` and and `apache2`. I've found several places that use `rpm` or `yum` to install this, but those aren't supported on my current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is a question regarding the Debian/GNU Linux OS rather than a Raspberry Pi specific one.

The package you are looking for is called libpam-mysql :)

Regards

Sven